# Валидация формы на девайсах

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

Здравствуйте. Делаю форму загрузки фотографии на сайт со стороны пользователя с валидацией и выводом миниатюр. На девайсах получаю ошибку ext_error при попытке загрузить уже имеющиеся в медиатеке фотографии, а если сфотографировать , то она проходит валидацию. Подскажите может что с кодом не так?

```
//Uploader
(function() {

    uploaded = 0;

    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select'),
        max_limit = 1;

    var upload = function(files) {

        if ((files.length <= max_limit) && ( uploaded < max_limit )) {

            var formData = new FormData(),
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                x;

            for (x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                formData.append('file[]', files[x]);
            }
            formData.append('action', 'upload');
            xhr.open('post', '');
            xhr.send(formData);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //Проверяем статус ошибки
                if (data['status'] === undefined) {

                    uploaded = uploaded + data.length;
                    displayUploads(data);

                } else {
                    if (data['status'] === "max_files_error") {
                        //Выводим ошибку "Вы не можете загрузить больше " + max_limit + " файлов"     
                    } else if (data['status'] === "ext_error") {
                        //Выводим ошибку "Разрешено загружать только jpg, gif, png."    
                    }
                }



            }
        } else {
            //Выводим ошибку "Sorry, you can download only one photo :("
        }

    }

    fileSelect.onchange = function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        upload(fileSelect.files);
    };

}());
```

А вот Серверный код :

```
private function upload_project_files($max_files = 1, $allowed_ext = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif' , 'tiff')) {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            //Ограничения на загрузку
            // $allowed_ext = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');
            // $max_files = 3;

            if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                $uploadedfiles = array();
                $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                $files = $_FILES['file'];


                if ( count($files['name']) > $max_files && count($files['name']) != 0) {
                    echo '{"status":"max_files_error"}';
                    exit;
                } 
                foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                    $ext = pathinfo($files['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    if(!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_ext)){
                        echo '{"status":"ext_error"}';
                        exit;
                    }
                }

                foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                  if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                    $file = array(
                      'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                      'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                      'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                      'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                      'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
                    );
                    $file = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);

                    $uploadedfiles[] = array('url' => $file['url'],'path' => $file['file']);
                  }
                }
            die(json_encode($uploadedfiles));
}
```

Comment: а какой формат файлов загружаете? точно проходит по фильтру?

Comment: Формат файлов скорее всего и не подходит. НО тогда вопрос - какие форматы файлов отправляет айфон например . По общим сведениям это стандартный набор, который у меня указан . В чём тогда дело?

Comment: в чем сложность посмотреть формат файлов? посмотрите, какого формата файлы в библиотеке устройства или какого формата файлы приходят на сервер. И я бы сразу добавил в `$allowed_ext` формат jpeg, вы его, видимо, забыли.

Comment: Формат - "JPG" , но он у меня указан. Даже с добавлением jpeg - дело не меняется .

Comment: не работает именно на айфоне, или вообще нигде? попробуйте `var_dump($_FILES);` сделать, чтобы проверить, что там приходит. Меня немного смущает, что вы обращаетесь к `$_FILES['file']['name']` как к массиву и перебираете его, хотя не похоже, что там должен быть массив.

Comment: На айфоне точно нет. Андроид еще не успел проверить , но тем не менее. На десктопе всё отлично

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43740/discussion-between---and-andrei-sukharev).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я был не внимателен и пропустил расширение ' Jpeg'. Скрипт полностью рабочий - кому надо.